# mysql: import csv in existing table

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, multiple-columns

Imagine you have a CSV file with only text in it and line ending `\r\n`.
like this:

`abc`
`def`
`hij`
...
`xyz`

You want to import this file in an existing multi-column table, where each line of text needs to go in a line of one specific (currently empty) column (lets name it `needed`) of the table. Like this:

`| a | b | c |needed|`
`|foo|bar|baz|______|`<-- abc
`|foo|bar|baz|______|`<-- def
...
`|foo|bar|baz|______|`<-- xyz

The data from the CSV file does not need to be inserted in a certain order. It really does not matter which field of `needed` has which data from the CSV in it, as long as every line gets imported, everything is fine.

I've tried lots of things and its driving me mad, but I can't figure out, how this could be done. Can this be solved somehow with LOAD DATA INFILE and update/replace/insert command? What would you do in a case like this? Is it even possible with mysql? Or do I need a custom php script for this?

I hope the question is clear enough. Please ask, if something is unclear to you.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, but it looks as though it's not immediately possible. It appears, from a quick look at the documentation, that you need to start by creating a temporary table, then `LOAD` the data into that and update your original table from the temporary. However, I can't see how the `UPDATE` query should be written. Your requirement that "_It really does not matter which field of stuff has which data from the csv in it_" is rather unusual and I can't immediately see how to get around it. What if there are more rows in `stuff` than in the file. Or fewer?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I have already imported the data in another table, but I'm stuck at how to update the data from that table with the first one. Exactly because "it does really not matter which field has which data" so I can't use `inner join` or something like that. The column of the created second table has indeed less rows than the `needed`one, but I could adjust that to match it exactly. That should not be the main problem. I'm just clueless on how to proceed from here, since I need to update over 600.000 lines like that...

Comment: Is `stuff` indexed? With a numeric primary key running from 1 to 600,000??

Comment: the column `a` has primary keys but not from 1-600k unfortunately. It looks more like: 308, 312, 318, 319, 320, 371 ... 655578

Comment: I don't see an easy way to get all these numbers from just this single column, copy them and put them in front of the other lines in the csv. If I knew how to do that without exporting the whole table (over 5gb, a real pain to open and edit/copy long stuff out of such a file), I could go the usual way of LOAD DATA INFILE to temp table and update with inner join...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here you go...

Add a new column to `stuff` populated with 1-600,000

```
ALTER TABLE stuff ADD COLUMN newId INTEGER UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Create a temp table for your CSV file

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data VARCHAR(32)
);
```

I'm guessing the required length of the data.

Import into the temporary table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE <wherever> INTO TABLE temp;
```

Add the data to `stuff`

```
UPDATE stuff AS s
JOIN temp AS t ON t.id=s.newId
SET s.needed=t.data;
```

Tidy up

```
DROP TABLE temp;
ALTER TABLE stuff DROP COLUMN newId;
```

I must admit that I haven't tested the `LOAD DATA INFILE` or the `UPDATE` statements, but I have checked all the table fiddling. In particular, MySQL will populate the `newId` column with consecutive numbers.

I don't think there will be a problem if the number of rows in `stuff` doesn't match the number of lines in your csv file - obviously, there will be a few rows with `needed` still NULL if there are fewer lines than rows.

Comment: I wrote this before reading your last comment - evidently you know better than I how to load the data and write the update query :-)

Comment: This looks really promising, I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Digging into `LOAD DATA INFILE` a bit more I'm not certain how it will react to trying to load a single field from a CSV file into a table with two columns. If it it complains, you need to use the "add a new column with `AUTO_INCREMENT`" trick again.

Comment: I'm still stuck with `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name UNIQUE INDEX AUTO_INCREMENT;` It gives me a syntax error, but I'm sure I find the reason and go on with the code from there ;)

Comment: Sorry! It should be `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name INTEGER UNIQUE INDEX AUTO_INCREMENT` - I'd missed the `INTEGER`. I've edited it above.

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 1`

Comment: Bah! Gets worse... I didn't use the word `INDEX` when I tested (on MySQL 5.1). Edited above...

Comment: I just tested this in a test environment and IT WORKS! You are a (mysql) genius. Thank you so much.

Comment: We aim to please :-)) (blush)

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way I found was with Libreoffice Calc+Base.
[Import/Export Data in Base.](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Importing_and_Exporting_Data_in_Base)

But becarefull,if you have "not null" options in columns and by mistake there is a cell which has no data in it, that row will be skiped.

So first disable the not null options from columns.

Oh and there is Microsoft Office Excel way,but I did not done it since it required a plugin to install and I was lazy.